# Using AWS Lambda and Python to Open a Webpage via URL and Grab the resulting webpage as PDF and Upload to S3

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using SES to receive emails, which comes in MIME type.  I need to find a URL in there (I know how to do this part), navigate to that URL, login to the site, "click" on file -> Download on the page that loads and download as CSV, and then upload to S3.

Is this even possible?

Thank you!!

Comment: Definitely possible. You could do 75% of that with the requests module or another urllib type library. you'll also need to use boto3 for S3

Comment: How do I use Pip with AWS Lambda?  I assume I need to install some directory or something to get this library to work.